# Почему передача по ссылке с модификатором in позволяет функции изменять передаваемый объект?

Tags: c#

```
class Computer
{
    Processor processor {get;set;}
}

class Processor
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

void Method1(in Computer computer)
{
    computer.processor.Name = "AMD Ryzen";
}

void Main()
{
    Computer computer = new() { processor = new() {Name = "Intel Pentium"}};
    new Method1(computer);
    Console.WriteLine(computer.processor.Name);
}
//Output: AMD Ryzen
```

Почему объект передаваемый по ссылке только для чтения изменяется?

Comment: Хм, может я с мобильного что не вижу, но где вы тут увидели "объект только для чтения"?

Comment: void Method1(in Computer computer)                        https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier

Comment: `Method1(in Computer computer)` означает, что вы не можете сделать в методе `computer = new Computer();`, а вот менять свойства с сеттерами это только в путь.

Comment: Понятно, in запрещает менять ссылку на объект но не сам объект, спасибо.

Comment: Можно как то передать объект чтобы метод не мог его изменять без создания дополнительных копий? Сеттер не подходит потому что объект должен изменяться в другом методе.